# Debug powershell in Visual studio code with parameters from command line

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

Using Powershell ISE I often set breakpoints in a script and start the script from command line. ISE then stops at the breakpoint and lets me debug from there. How do I do the same from Terminal in Visual Studio Code? Below is a script just to show you what I mean. Starting from a terminal I would write:

```
.\hello.ps1 -firstName "firstName" -lastName "theLastName"
```

But doing that from terminal it just starts a new window.

```ps
param(
[string]$firstName,
[string]$lastName
)

Write-Host "Starting test script"
try
{
   Write-Host "Hello $firstName $lastName"        
}
catch
{
    Write-Error "Error. Exception: $_"
}

write-host "Script done"
```

Answer (score 19):

To make the info from [Eickhel Mendoza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6028806/eickhel-mendoza)'s link explicit - the solution is to set up a **Run and Debug config file**. This is created in `.vscode/launch.json`. The content for this case would be:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Hello Script",
            "type": "PowerShell",
            "request": "launch",
            "script": "${workspaceFolder}\\hello.ps1",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "args": ["-firstName \"firstName\" -lastName \"theLastName\""]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then just open the "Run and Debug" sidebar pane on VSCode (the play button with the bug or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), where you can run your launch script and any breakpoints you set will be hit as expected.

Comment: Where does this file live?  Under the folder where the ps1 is?  I am not using workspace, just plain old ps1 files.  Will adding this magical file make it work?  Will other pwsh scripts then use that file as well?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the concept of workspaces but afaik the `.vscode` folder just lives at the root of the folder you have open in VSCode. This If you want to run a different file looks like you just add a new object to the `configurations` array - more information [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this might help... it involves modifying the launch.json file in your workspace.

https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/tree/master/examples#passing-arguments-to-the-script

Comment: It is best to post suggestions as comment rather than as answer.